# Unity c# - how to sort Resources.LoadAll<sprite> array?

Tags: c#, sorting, unity-game-engine

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjGbA.png)

I made sprite array by using Resources.LoadAll. But Resources.LoadAll doesn't load assets as they are seen in my project tab

Project tab list shows objects as like 1,2,3.. Resources.LoadAll returns as like 1, 10, 100, 2, 20, 200..

How to sort sprite array in ascending order?

I tried Array.Sort but noting seems to change

```
Sprite[] box = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Images");
Array.Sort(box, delegate(Sprite x, Sprite y) { return x.name.CompareTo(y.name); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort the array based on the parsed integer value

```
var arr = box.OrderBy(n.name => int.Parse(n.name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Becuase `name` is a string you're getting alphabetical sorting - what you want is numeric sorting.

If `name` is just a number then convert it to an `int` and compare it:

```
Sprite[] box = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Images");
Array.Sort(box, delegate(Sprite x, Sprite y) {return int.Parse(x.name).CompareTo(int.Parse(y.name)); });
```

If the number is contained within the name (i.e there is alphabetic text in there as well) then you'll need to extract the number, convert it to an `int` and then compare it.